# How to navigate to a particular activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I am having 3 activities. From the third activity, I need to come back to the 1st activity when a GUI button is clicked. I know I can click the "physical" back button 2 times to make this but that is not an option.

So, is there any way I can display the 1st activity, *without creating a new instance*? I can pass the 1st activity's instance to the third activity, no issue with that.

Comment: use navigation drawer in combination with action bar. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) in your intent.

From the documentation:

> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

To use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FirstActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: In which class should I add this? In the first activity or the third? I added to third, seems like not working

Comment: The documentation explains exactly what you're trying to do (see edit). If it's not working, you must be doing something else incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(src_ctxt, dest.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
src_ctxt.startActivity(intent);
```

This should do it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your activity B singleInstance that if it's already create you don't want to create again, that is [launch mode of the activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) can be defined in manifest android:launchMode that defines how the activity will be instanciated.

in your case use android:launchMode="singleInstance"

**or**

You can use flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. If the activity is already running it will bring that to front instead of creating new activity.

Comment: "You can use flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ..." not the truth ... ;)

Comment: This flag will make activity as a start of new task. else you can also use FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, which will load activity if it is in history stack.